# Zend_db limits string to 255 characters?

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I have trouble when I want to `SELECT a vachar(4000)` data from SQL Server to PHP. Indeed, when I execute the `$db->query` I have a string limited to 255 caracters.

I tried to cast the data and nothing happened, it stays truncated. From SQL Server I have no problem whith my request.
I also tried to substring my data into many subdata limited to 255 characters, and that didn't work.

I think it's a problem from `Zend_Db_Table`. Are there any parameters to force it to take all the data?

Comment: version of  SQL  Server  ?

Comment: Did you try this query directly on your SQL?

Comment: The SQL Server version is 2005.
Yes i Have already try the request in my SQL interface and it works, i have the data with its 4000 caracters. But it's when Zend_Db or PHP receive the data or give the truncated data.

Comment: Never seen this problem, could be a problem with some kind of special chars? Is the charset set for db connection to utf-8 ? Maybe just an output problem?

Comment: are you sure you're using the correct Zend_Db adapter for your database and the correct PHP extension.